# Is there a way to render the images from the stream of youtube video data or any video stream data?

Tags: image-processing

I want to know how to get the images of a particular video strem data?
What are the ways to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify...are you wanting to get a screenshot from a youtube video?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of your favorite downloading tools/extensions to download the video file to your computer.  Then get and use ffmpeg, with the following command line:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 image_%3d.jpg
```